# C# Excel Add In: Get active worksheet as XML

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2013, excel-addins

I have a working Word add in, which saves the selected part of the document (including images, tables, etc) as an XML string in a database. The add in can also retrieve previously saved XML strings and insert it into the current position of the currently open document, preserving styling and formatting.

I want to do almost the same for Excel. I want to get an XML string that represents the active worksheet, save that to the database and then later retrieve that XML string and insert it as a worksheet into the active workbook.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to obtain that XML string, nor can I figure out how to insert it as a worksheet. I have been experimenting and searching for hours, but to no avail.

Getting the active sheet seems easy:

```
dynamic sheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
```

But I haven't been able to get any further.

For reference, this is how I got the XML string in Word:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection currentSelection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;
string xmlString = currentSelection.XML;
```

To insert it, I used:

```
string xmlString = ...; // Read the string for the database.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection currentSelection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;
currentSelection.InsertXML(xmlString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in [this sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/How-to-convert-excel-file-7a9bb404).
In this sample they are converting the Excel Sheet into a `DataTable` by iterating over the rows and cells and converting the `DataTable` into a string.

Comment: I need to preserve all the data in the sheet, including graphs, formatting, etc., not just the values of the individual cells. That's why I specifically ask about the worksheet itself, not the values.